# Update an insert query

Tags: sql, database, stored-procedures, oracle11g, oracle10g

I'm new to db, so my question may be wrong.

What I tried to achieve is to fetch rows from table, edit two columns and insert to same table.

```
INSERT INTO table_name 
    (SELECT * 
     FROM table_name 
     WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = 1 );
```

But before add inserting I want to update the fields

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET UPDATED_DATE = '20161208', 
    STATUS = 'updated' 
WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = 1;
```

Do I need to write a stored procedure to achieve this?

If so how it should be?

Comment: No stored procedure needed. Do you want rows added to the table, then do `INSERT INTO t SELECT c1, literals, etc FROM t`. Else simply do UPDATE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are learning databases.  When you use `INSERT` you should *always* list the columns, unless you know exactly what you are doing.  So, list the explicit columns and put in the values that you want:

```
INSERT INTO table_name( . . ., UPDATED_DATE, STATUS)
    SELECT . . ., '20161208', 'updated'
    FROM table_name
    WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = 1;
```

You can do this in a single statement.

Answer (score 0):

Stored procedures are generally used for the SQL operations (reusable code) which needs to be done repeatedly with dynamic values being passed to it (if required).

If you are just looking to run these 2 queries for one time update operation, stored procedure is not recommended. You can run these 2 commands as a single transaction and commit the transaction as a single Atomic transaction.

Comment: But i want to update two fields before insert back. Will a single transaction do it? or it will take the all entries with TRANSACTION_ID = 1 and do update?

Answer (score 0):

What do you want to achieve is to duplicate a line in your table and modify some fields of this duplicated line ?

If so, you need to do something like this (don't put the TRANSACTION_ID in field list. Normally it should create automatically an ID_TRANSACTION 2 if you have Identity) :

```
INSERT INTO TableName (field1, field2, ...)
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = 1
```

And then :

```
UPDATE table_name SET UPDATED_DATE = '20161208', STATUS = 'updated' WHERE TRANSACTION_ID = 2;
```

Comment: No need for that additional UPDATE. Simply specify the values in the INSERT's SELECT list.

Comment: @REK you understood what i wanted to do, but in my case TRANSACTION_ID is not a unique id, my table will have 2 entries per TRANSACTION_ID and when i duplicate, it will create 2 more entries with same TRANSACTION_ID. For that reason i can't use your solution.